# When do serversocket.accept() throws an exception? [java]

Tags: java, sockets, exception, timer, timertask

I want to have a counter of how much incoming connections I have per second. That means, I have made a loop like this one:

```
int incomingConnections;
while(true) {
  try {
     Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
     incomingConnections++;
  } catch (Exception ex) {
  }
```

Before, I started a TimerTask like this:

```
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("TimerTask: " + incominConnections + " incoming Connections while the last second.");
                incominConnections = 0;
            }
        }, 0, 1000);
```

What do I need to do, because I want the int only to count when it accepts a connection succesfull, not everytime it iterates the loop.
Any help out there?
Thx

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do with the TimerTask. That is irrelevant to your question as far as I can tell. Also it doesn't do anything. Why did you include it?

Comment: 'Every time it iterates the loop' and 'when it accepts a connection successfully' are the same thing in the code you posted. If an exception is thrown, the counter isn't incremented. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code already does what you want.

The Java documentation for ServerSocket.accept() states that it:

> Listens for a connection to be made to this socket and accepts it. The method blocks until a connection is made.

So because the call to accept blocks, you will only ever increment your counter if a connection is successfully made.

If an exception is thrown in the call to accept() you will enter the catch block, without executing the code that increments the counter.